# Why does curvature $\kappa = x'y''-x''y'$ for plane curve?

Tags: differential-geometry

Why does curvature $\kappa = x'y''-x''y'$ for plane curve? And it is also given as $\theta'$. Thanks!

Comment: This is not correct without further assumptions. What formula(s) do *you* know for curvature? Can you explain why curvature for a (suitably parametrized) plane curve is in fact $\theta'$ (what's $\theta$, by the way)?

Comment: $\theta$ is the angel that the tangent indicatrix makes with the x-axis. I know curvature is $\frac{|\alpha'(s) \times \alpha''(s)|}{|\alpha'(s)|^3}.$

And it's also $|\alpha''(s)|$ for arc length parameterized curves I believe.

Comment: So when your curve is arclength-parametrized, you'll get the formula you gave in the question.